# jquery and part-find names

Tags: jquery

I have many INPUT tags with the following name structure:
name="menu:popSearch:chk0"
name="menu:popSearch:chk1"
name="menu:popSearch:chk2"
name="menu:popSearch:chk3"

and so on.

What jQuery will give me the INPUT 's that follow this structure.

(It's to run the sites http://BiblePro.BibleOcean.com and http://BahaiResearch.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean find all the inputs with popSearch in the name,

you can use

```
var list = $("input[name*='popSearch']")
```

that will get you an array of those elements that have popSearch in the name

Comment: You can also use `$("input[name*='menu\\:popSearch\\:chk'])` to match more strictly names. Colon has to be escaped if you want to include it in search pattern.

Comment: What about all those INPUTS where they are checked ?

Comment: answers in the other quetion you asked :)